# Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT - Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I am getting this exception about commits but am not sure what exactly is wrong with my Stored Procedure. I have read answers in other questions but am unable to find where exactly the commit count is getting messed up.

Herewith the Stored Procedure I use:

```
USE [AFS_GROUP]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SBO_SP_TransactionNotification]    Script Date: 12/12/2012 10:41:57 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[SBO_SP_TransactionNotification] 

@object_type nvarchar(20),              -- SBO Object Type
@transaction_type nchar(1),         -- [A]dd, [U]pdate, [D]elete, [C]ancel, C[L]ose
@num_of_cols_in_key int,
@list_of_key_cols_tab_del nvarchar(255),
@list_of_cols_val_tab_del nvarchar(255)

AS

begin

-- Return values
declare @error  int             -- Result (0 for no error)
declare @error_message nvarchar (200)       -- Error string to be displayed
select @error = 0
select @error_message = N'Ok'

IF @object_type = 13 AND @transaction_type = 'A'
BEGIN
  UPDATE INV1   
  SET U_jnl1='N', U_jnl2='N', U_jnl3='N', U_jnl4='N'
  WHERE DocEntry = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del    

  DECLARE @CallIDo13 VARCHAR(10) = (SELECT TOP 1 [U_HEATID] FROM OINV WHERE [DocEntry] = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del);
  DECLARE @DocNumo13 VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 [DocNum] FROM OINV WHERE [DocEntry] = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del);
  EXEC [AFSJHBSQL01].[HEAT].[dbo].[uspCreateJournalFromINV] @CallIDo13, @DocNumo13, @object_type;
END
ELSE IF @object_type = 14 AND @transaction_type = 'A'
BEGIN
  UPDATE RIN1
  SET U_jnl1='N', U_jnl2='N', U_jnl3='N', U_jnl4='N'
  WHERE DocEntry = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del
END
ELSE IF @object_type = 15 AND @transaction_type = 'A'
BEGIN
  UPDATE DLN1
  SET U_jnl1='N', U_jnl2='N', U_jnl3='N', U_jnl4='N'
  WHERE DocEntry = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del    

  DECLARE @CallIDo15 VARCHAR(10) = (SELECT TOP 1 [U_HEATID] FROM ODLN WHERE DocEntry = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del);
  DECLARE @DocNumo15 VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 [DocNum] FROM ODLN WHERE DocEntry = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del);
  EXEC [AFSJHBSQL01].[HEAT].[dbo].[uspCreateJournalFromDN] @CallIDo15, @DocNumo15, @object_type;
END
ELSE IF @object_type = 16 AND @transaction_type = 'A'
BEGIN
  UPDATE RDN1
  SET U_jnl1='N', U_jnl2='N', U_jnl3='N', U_jnl4='N'
  WHERE DocEntry = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del
END
ELSE IF @object_type = 17 AND @transaction_type = 'A'
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ItemCode VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 [ItemCode] FROM [RDR1] WHERE [DocEntry] = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del AND ([ItemCode] = 'VIU Chip Prod' OR [ItemCode] = 'FPR Chip Production'));
  DECLARE @Desc VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 [CardName] FROM ORDR WHERE [DocEntry] = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del);
  --DECLARE @CallID VARCHAR(10) = (SELECT TOP 1 [U_HEATID] FROM ORDR WHERE [DocEntry] = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del);
  IF (@ItemCode = 'VIU Chip Prod')
  BEGIN
      EXEC [AFSJHBSQL01].[HEAT].[dbo].[uspCreateHeatJobFromSO] @list_of_cols_val_tab_del, @ItemCode, @Desc;
      --RETURN;
  END
  ELSE IF(@ItemCode = 'FPR Chip Production')
  BEGIN
      EXEC [AFSJHBSQL01].[HEAT].[dbo].[uspCreateHeatJobFromSO] @list_of_cols_val_tab_del, @ItemCode, @Desc;
    --RETURN;
  END
END
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Select the return values
select @error, @error_message
END
```

Comment: Could it be a problem within or related to one of the other stored procedures you are calling?

Comment: Agree with @dan1111. The code you have posted doesn't have a `BEGIN TRAN` look in the called stored procs.

Comment: This is the only stored procedure that makes the call to the remote database. Is there anyway someone can relook at the begin trans and commit statements and make the adjustments.